# Display FigCaption from Media library

Tags: c#, xml, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

Using Sitecore 6.5, for `jpg` we want to display a `FigCaption` in the HTML mark up such as

```
<figure> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100" alt="">
    <figcaption>Figcaption content</figcaption>
</figure>
```

These are stored in the Sitecore template for jpegs in `Exif.Copyright` field, but how do we retrieve this in code?

I can access the `MediaItem` using the code below but that doesn't give me access to `Exif.Copyright`

```
MediaItem media = ((ImageField)item.Fields[fieldName]).MediaItem;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the inner item on the media item, and get the field values.

```
var field = media.InnerItem.Fields["Copyright"]
```

Comment: Worked beautifully just with the field name "Copyright". Thank you. Dunston if you update the field name, I will will mark this answer as accepted.